# What is the structure of the sentence 'const to the rescue'?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

The following is the context:

> Despite my fastidious coding habits, I
>   have made a silly mistake and typed +=
>   when I meant to type +. As a result,
>   when concatUnsafe is called, it will
>   modify the arguments out and s1, which
>   may come as surprise to the user who
>   would expect a concatenation function
>   to modify one of the source strings?
>
> *const to the rescue.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"*X* to the rescue" is an idiom that means that *X* is coming to save us from a bad situation.  It means that *const* will be the solution to the problem.  Using this idiom is a more playful and informal way of saying this.

Comment: Thank you,english is something strange,so do other languages! It confused me for a long time!

Answer (score 1):

It can be thought as omitting a couple of words:

> `const` [is coming] to the rescue.

In other words, `const` will save you from making the programming mistake described in the text. (By the look of it, the author is talking about strings in C, which are indeed a potential minefield - so tread carefully!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice of c programming.

Comment: So += is how we concatenate strings in C?

Comment: @Shinto: I was thinking that the function was computing the offset in the destination string at which to append the second source string, or something like that...but on reflection, I may just be digging a hole for myself... :-)

Comment: @Shint, @Steve: seems to be C++ and std::string.